# Update the help on the review page

Tags: support, help-improvement

I stumbled over the help near the review queues. I think it might need an updated version of the screenshots.

> Help improve the site
>
> Stack Overflow is moderated by [you](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

The used screenshots: [image: old one]

compared to the actual one:
[image: actual one]

have big differences. Would it be possible to update the screenshots?

Comment: The differences are because one is for answers, and the other is for questions. See the titles at the top.

Comment: You are right, I updated the image.